# Increasing underline size in ggplot title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to increase the size/width/thickness of the underline in the ggplot title. I have tried using size, width, and length but with no luck.

Here is a example of what I have done.

```
test <- tibble(x = 1:5, 
y = 1, 
z = x ^ 2 + y)

ggplot(test, aes(x,z)) +
geom_point() +
labs(title = expression(paste(underline("Increasing"), " underline")))+
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Nice question. Did I get it right at the first idea?

Overplot the underline with another underline.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

test <- tibble(x = 1:5, 
               y = 1, 
               z = x ^ 2 + y)

ggplot(test, aes(x, z)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = expression(paste(underline(underline("Increasing")), " underline"))) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]

Comment: It sounded like a great idea but when I tried on the example and the intended plot its spaces the lines.