# How to increase the width of underline drawed in legend labels in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my ggplot chart:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(cyl,mpg, color = cyl)) + scale_color_continuous(labels = c(expression(underline("Above 65 & over")),
                  expression(underline("45 - 64")),expression(underline("25 - 44")), expression(underline("15 - 24")),expression(underline("Under 15"))))
```

**First**: I want to increase the width of my underline. How can I do this? Also the end of this underline can be an arrow?
Is there any package that helps to do this?

**Second**, I would like to know how to find out the arguments that expression functions can accepts.?

Comment: See `?plotmath` for different options, but they are limited. I don't think you can change the line width. Maybe you can have a look at something like `ggtext`.

Comment: @Axeman thanks for your time. I looked at `ggtext` but there is a small number of css elements. I couldnt do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is to draw in the lines "manually" with grid, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)

png(filename = "example.png", width = 480, height = 480)
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(cyl,mpg, color = cyl)) +
  scale_color_continuous(labels = c(expression(underline(" Above 65 & over")),
                                    expression(underline("45 - 64")),
                                    expression(underline("25 - 44")),
                                    expression(underline("15 - 24")),
                                    expression(underline("Under 15"))))
grid.lines(x = c(0.89, 0.98), y = 0.592,
           arrow = arrow(length = unit(1.5, "mm"), ends = "first"))
grid.lines(x = c(0.91, 0.98), y = 0.547,
           arrow = arrow(length = unit(1.5, "mm"), ends = "first"))
grid.lines(x = c(0.91, 0.98), y = 0.502,
           arrow = arrow(length = unit(1.5, "mm"), ends = "first"))
grid.lines(x = c(0.91, 0.98), y = 0.457,
           arrow = arrow(length = unit(1.5, "mm"), ends = "first"))
grid.lines(x = c(0.831, 0.98), y = 0.414,
           arrow = arrow(length = unit(1.5, "mm"), ends = "first"))
grid.gedit("GRID.line", gp = gpar(lwd = 2))
dev.off()
```

[image: example.png]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

This approach has the advantages and disadvantages, e.g. you can make the lines look exactly how you want them to look, but you have to specify exactly where on the plot they will be drawn and you can't rescale the plot dynamically (i.e. you need to specify the dimensions of the final plot before you draw the lines). I would be very interested to find out if there is a better way of solving this problem.

For more info on grid graphics:

- https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/the-grid-package.html
- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/doc/index.html
- The R Graphics book by Paul Murrell

Comment: thanks for your time! I will look into this package

Comment: another option, albeit somewhat hacky, would be to create a fake legend (and stitch plots together e.g. with patchwork) and use annotate for arrow segments and text for more dynamic positioning.

Answer (score 1):

[Copied from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344066/increasing-underline-size-in-ggplot-title) - which seems to solve at least the width problem.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(cyl,mpg, color = cyl)) + 
  scale_color_continuous(labels = c(expression(paste(underline(underline(underline("Above 65 & over"))))),
                                    expression(underline("45 - 64")),
                                    expression(underline("25 - 44")),
                                    expression(underline("15 - 24")),
                                    expression(underline("Under 15"))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: If you still believe this question is a duplicate, you can now vote to close the question - the bounty has gone.

Comment: @halfer I think it's a semi-duplicate. Although I believe that marking as a duplicate helps to increase visibility of (very) linked questions, I think the interested person will see this question now in the linked questions and that should be enough